# What are the advantages of Mojarra JSF over IBM JSF (which is by default on Websphere7 server)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere, websphere-7, mojarra

I am using Websphere7 server and it is shipped with a default IBM version of JSF. Are there any benefits that I may get from overriding the default IBM JSF with Mojarra JSF?

If I use Mojarra with Webspehere7, will I gain something?Should I go with the default IBM JSF implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you do and need.

WebSphere Application Server 7 already comes with two different JSF flavors. One the Mojorra and the other one is MyFaces. You can even switch the implementation in the [WebSphere Administration Console](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftweb_jsf.html&resultof=%22myfaces%22%20%22myfac%22). They added some WebSphere specific patches.

I'm not sure if they update the JSF implementation with their fix packs. If you need a specific patch you could go for the original implementation, however I would usually stay with the default implementation.

The built in libraries for WAS7 are JSF 1.2, because its a Java EE 5 server. When exchanging the libraries you can use JSF 2.0. Make sure you set up the classloading correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is only slight difference. Basically some of the original JSF libraries has been replaced with some others to work smoothly with IBM Websphere. So it's not recommended to use Mojarra (and you don't have any reason for that) because it can cause you unnecessary problems. Also see this [article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/cweb_javaserver_faces.html) from IBM.

Comment: Mojarra version of JSF comes straight from Oracle and it is more stable than IBM version of JSF. As IBM has created their vesion of JSF to incorporate with their Websphere server.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any benefits that I may get from overriding the default IBM JSF with Mojarra JSF ?

No, There are no extra benifits. The specification is same only the implementation differs.

Mojarra is implemented by Oracle. It is more stable implementation of JSF.

yes, you can go with default IBM JSF implementation.